# Twilio for SaaS(multi tenant) based web application

Tags: twilio

I'm developing SaaS based web application with voip feature. I know that twilio is one of the best solution but I need to know how it will work when come to subscription based application,

My requirement is when user subscribe to application, he can start working of calling with further set up. Does twilio support this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Twilio supports SaaS applications.

I can think of two ways to handle multiple tenants:

- Using [subacconts](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2011/02/announcing-twilio-subaccounts.html);
- Buying a different [phoneNumber](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services/api/phonenumber-resource) for each tenant;

Using subaccounts adds another layer of complexity to your application, but you'll have a better separation of each tenant's data and some useful features.

Both of these options can be used programmatically, so no further action is required for the user of your application.